# What is the null-object error with this AS3 code for loading external swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, null, flash

I am getting a null object error when I add the mouse event listener for the log in button. (Look at the comments in the constructor)

I am using Flash CS6, and objects such as logInbutton and screen_log_in are instance names from the .fla file. This here is the .as file.

Error I get is:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at actions::indexPage()
```

My AS3 code:

```
package actions
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class indexPage extends MovieClip
{
    public function indexPage():void
    {
        loadSWF("http://mathlympics.cu.cc/loginsystem.swf");

        //THIS IS THE LINE WHICH IS CAUSING THE ERROR
        //WHEN I COMMENT IT OUT THE ERROR IS GONE
        logInButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToLogIn);
    }

    var _swfLoader:Loader;
    var _swfContent:MovieClip;

    public function loadSWF(path:String):void 
    {
       var _req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
       _req.url = path;

       _swfLoader = new Loader();
       setupListeners(_swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo);

       _swfLoader.load(_req);
    }

    function setupListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void 
    {
       dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
    }

    function addSWF(event:Event):void 
    {
       event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
       event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preloadSWF);
       _swfContent = event.target.content;
       screen_log_in.addChild(_swfContent);
    }

    function unloadSwf():void
    {
        _swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
        screen_log_in.removeChild(_swfContent);
        _swfContent = null;
    }

    function goToLogIn(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        unloadSwf();
        screen_log_in.loadSWF("http://mathlympics.cu.cc/loginsystem.swf");
    }

    function goToRegister(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        unloadSwf();
        screen_log_in.loadSWF("http://mathlympics.cu.cc/register.swf");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying logInButton is null. Have you made sure to link the instances in flash to actionscript?

Comment: ^The 'Export for ActionScript' option in the properties of the instance.

Comment: @JonoRR The instance name is logInButton. The name of the movieclip in library is logInButton as well.

Comment: But when you right click on it, go into properties; do you have that checkbox checked?

Comment: @JonoRR no, that does not seem to solve the problem. Is there any other possibility for this error?

Comment: Where's your as3 code sitting?

Comment: oh wait, is that a separate project in Flash Builder or something? And that SWF you're importing (loginsystem.swf) has the logInButton inside it?

Comment: is IndexPage your document class ?

Comment: @prototypical yes indexPage is my documetnClass

Comment: Yre you sure that your button is name logInButton and not loginButton ? Also, how many keyframes are on your timeline ? Does that login button exist on the first keyframe on your timeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to answer my question for the future visitors. The cause of problem I have note been able to figure out but what I have figured out is how to get around it. I simply copy pasted my code from document class to the frames and it works absolutely fine there.

Answer (score 2):

You can not access stage until stage is available.

```
public function indexPage():void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init)
}

public function init(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init)
    loadSWF("http://mathlympics.cu.cc/loginsystem.swf");

    //THIS IS THE LINE WHICH IS CAUSING THE ERROR
    //WHEN I COMMENT IT OUT THE ERROR IS GONE
    logInButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToLogIn);
}
```

Comment: Oh yup. This'll be it. I'd also note that as part of not accessing the stage, you can't access object instances on the stage.

Comment: This is not not solving the problem. Any other guesses.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at actions::indexPage/init()